# Forecasting Waves

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing, forecasting

I have an interesting Forecasting problem. I have a set of waves that I am trying to filter and recombine (see link). I am thinking to use a moving average for each but this doesn't give the results I would like.

[Image of waves to be forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WadWc.png)

I think the waves are really a sinusoid around a moving average that would give a better result, but the issue with this is that the moving average doesn't easily allow you to forecast where it is going to.

I would be interested if anyone knows a good model to use to estimate each wave that would give better forecasting performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out neural networks on the frequency domain transforms of those waves. Where the input is the previous n samples and the output is the next sample.

Comment: I'm just wondering in how to do this exactly as I have not used DFT for forecasting before. I take it you would have N sub waves (determined by the power spectrum) and then you use say M lags so your input space is N*M?

Comment: Yes exactly. I think this is worth trying.